# What kind/type of Qanun music is this?

Tags: identify-this-genre, unknown-performer

[Qanun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qanun_(instrument)) music comes in a wide variety, but what is the genre of [this sharp toned version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJIN9-tIlLo) of qanun music?

The video indicates that it is an extract from an album titled "Music of Islam, Volume 1: Al-Qahiroh (The Music of Cairo)". I find this music to be a thousand times better than other qanun tones, really very emotional.

This is the instrument for the people who don't know it.

[image: qanun]

Answer (score 2):

Sufi music: Mostafa Abd El Khalek

[Qanun Solo - An improvisation on the Egyptian box zither](http://www.deezer.com/track/63789947)